# How can I make li background visible as well with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Javascript as below:

```
$(function(){

    div = $("#titlelist");

    ul = $('#titlelist li');

    ul.css({overflow: 'hidden'});


    ul.each(function(){
        $(this).css({overflow: 'hidden'});
        $(this).mouseenter(function(e){               
            $(this).css({overflow: 'visible', background:'#CCC', 'z-index': '100'});

        });
        $(this).mouseleave(function(e){               
            $(this).css({overflow: 'hidden', background:''});

        });
    });
});
```

HTML as below:

```
<div id="container">
    <ul id="titlelist">
        <li>GBin1 Page view monitor Demo</li>
        <li>GBin1 Page view monitor Demo</li>
        <li>GBin1 Page view monitor Demo</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When mouse enter, only li content and part of background color can be visible, how can I make the background visible for all li content as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` code pieces add this line for the li's

```
$('li', this).css( ... );
```

Comment: Not quite understand your code, could you please explain this?thanks!

Comment: the this statement helps jQuery narrow down to the li's  under the ul. Like you change the ul styling, similarly li's can also be styled

Comment: but actually i already styled li as below:
 ul = $('#titlelist li');

Comment: oh my bad. So u mean you want not only the lines around the li's but the whole space around the set of li's to have the same style? In that case, you can simply apply your style to the whole `ul` and get rid of the individual li styling. That would cover the whole section comprising all the li's.